# Text sections need to be displayed left to right

Tags: html, css, text, flexbox

I want these 3 sections of text to display from left to right, with section 1 being on the far left and section 3 being on the far right, here is the CSS for them:

```
.mission {
max-width: 300px;
margin-top: 10rem
}

.qual {
max-width: 500px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: -10rem;
}

.please {
max-width: 300px;
padding-left: 60rem;
margin-top: -12rem;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div class="mission">
    <p>Our Mission is to provide a safe, reliable, loving, and caring service to each and every one of our furry friends</p>
</div>

<div class="qual">
    <p>Im fully qualified with Animal Management Level 3 at Distinction level, Canine Behaviour, Beginner Canine Trainer, Ultrasound Oral Care Qualification, Fully Insured, DBS Criminal Record Checked Clear, Dog First Aid & Emergency Canine Care Trained, Professional, Friendly, Reliable and Punctual.</p>
</div>

<div class="please">
    <p>Please explore our site and if we can help with your Dog Care or other Pet Care requirements then please get in touch.</p> 
</div>

</div>
```

```css
    .mission {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin-top: 10rem
    }
    
    .qual {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -10rem;
    }
    
    .please {
    max-width: 300px;
    padding-left: 60rem;
    margin-top: -12rem;
    }
```

```html
<div class="colorblock">
    <div class="description">

    <div class="mission">
        <p>Our Mission is to provide a safe, reliable, loving, and caring service to each and every one of our furry friends</p>
    </div>

    <div class="qual">
        <p>Im fully qualified with Animal Management Level 3 at Distinction level, Canine Behaviour, Beginner Canine Trainer, Ultrasound Oral Care Qualification, Fully Insured, DBS Criminal Record Checked Clear, Dog First Aid & Emergency Canine Care Trained, Professional, Friendly, Reliable and Punctual.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="please">
        <p>Please explore our site and if we can help with your Dog Care or other Pet Care requirements then please get in touch.</p> 
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Right now i have them displaying from left to right in their own sections of text, but the symmetry between them is off and skewed, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Ive tried many different variations of code, either ruins the layout of the text or just does not work, i am still inexperienced so im probably having a silly issue

Comment: Can you create a snippet that contains your HTML as well?

Comment: Yea, just added sorry about that

Comment: I have edited your question and added a snippet with your HTML and CSS that you can test. Can you confirm it reproduces your problem?

Comment: Its now fixed! not sure what you did but i'm thankful,

Comment: I would be proud if I solved the problem, but the reality is that I have just pasted your HTML and Javascript code, so it seems your code was already correct, but you had some issue that prevented you from seeing it, for example, it's possible that things were cached in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mission,
.qual,
.please {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-direction: row;
    top: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    
}

.colorblock .description {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10rem;
  max-width: 1600px;
  top: auto;
  bottom: auto;


}


.qual {
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colorblock">
    <div class="description">

    <div class="mission">
        <p>Our Mission is to provide a safe, reliable, loving, and caring service to each and every one of our furry friends</p>
    </div>

    <div class="qual">
        <p>Im fully qualified with Animal Management Level 3 at Distinction level, Canine Behaviour, Beginner Canine Trainer, Ultrasound Oral Care Qualification, Fully Insured, DBS Criminal Record Checked Clear, Dog First Aid & Emergency Canine Care Trained, Professional, Friendly, Reliable and Punctual.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="please">
        <p>Please explore our site and if we can help with your Dog Care or other Pet Care requirements then please get in touch.</p> 
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This seemed to fix my issue, i added a div wrapper named "description" so that i could have all the text within that div and then edit the CSS of the new div

Comment: What seemed to fix your issue? What did you change?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry for being vague, ive just made an edit that describes what i did to fix my issue